# Hamburger Menus

Tags: navigation, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, responsive-design

I was developing a personal website i wanna know this 
[image: Case 1]

or simply Hamburger is better

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is research out there showing that people are more likely to click a button labeled "Menu" rather than a hamburger icon, but that says little about their motivation. ("Menu" is a relatively vague term, whereas a hamburger is slowly becoming a standard symbol for a specific kind of menu: a top-level navigation menu.) Norman and Nielsen [advocate labeling the button](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/magnifying-glass-icon/).

I'd question whether you need the hamburger menu, though.

If you have few navigation items, consider using a navigation bar anchored at the top. If a person will need quick access to this navigation, consider a bar that hides on scroll down, but shows up as soon as one scrolls up.

If you have numerous navigation items, consider showing the navigation sidebar persistently or showing it by default and allowing the user to hide it with a button.